# Is there any way instead of a JS hack where I can post from an iframe to another page outside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, post, parent, pci-dss

Is there any way instead of a JS hack where I can post from an iframe to another page outside the iframe?

the iframe is posting data to a 3rd party and then just responding back with a URL which is the redirection URl thus we cannot set the form target. We are PCI compliant and thus we cannot use `window.parent.location = url;`

Comment: when you say "instead of a JS hack" do you mean in pure HTML; or "proper Javascript"  ??

Comment: I'm just looking for another way to do it instea dof doing a 
parent.location using JS.

Comment: OP: Are you still having this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it boils down to, it seems, is this:
1. You get a text url from a 3rd party in the iframe.
2. You want to **change your page's location** to that url.
3. Unless you have control over that 3rd party, all you are going to get is that text url.

Now, the only way to **change your page's location** automatically is with `window.parent.location` (or `window.location`.)

If changing the url of the page with javascript is not PCI compliant then you're trying to do something that is not PCI complicant.

Answer (score 0):

`<form>` accepts a target parameter, e.g. target="_parent"

Comment: the iframe is posting data to a 3rd party and then just responding back with a URL which is the redirection URl thus we cannot set the form target.

Comment: How do you mean "responding back"... it gives a 301 or 302, or actually returns the URL as JSON / XML / something else?

Answer (score 0):

In an anchor tag you can set `target='_parent'` this will cause the url to be loaded into the parent window.

Comment: the iframe is posting data to a 3rd party and then just responding back with a URL which is the redirection URl thus we cannot set the target.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, the only way is by using javascript. But it's not really a hack to use `window.parent.location = url;`

Comment: We are PCI compliant and thus we cannot use that.